# arrange spritenodes in patterns along the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, flappy-bird-clone

I dont know if you have played the mobile-game **Flappy Fall**. Its a simple game whit "falling"(scrolling) birds in a certain pattern, you have to catch them in a nest before they hit the ground. I am currently trying to learn a thing or two about Sprite-Kit and i am curious what is the best way to achieve different patterns in scrolling sprite-nodes? Lets say they are scrolling down the screen from one side to another and randomly have small waves and big waves. Any tips will be appreciated !

I am not trying to copy the game, just learn technics!

Comment: You mean the speed/rate at which they are added to the screen increases and decreases?

Comment: If so, do you mean in a controlled manner/patter or randomly?

Comment: There is a good and in-detail tutorial which helps to learn basics of Sprite Kit. It explains with a Flappy Bird example. Probably it will help you. http://mytechspace.com/2014/02/tutorial-how-to-develop-flappy-bird-game-in-ios-using-spritekit.html

Comment: The speed of the nodes is fairly easy to adjust, its more the pattern and how to place them when they are about to enter the screen!